# Why is my borewell pump drawing 6kW when it's rated 3kW?

Tags: motor, three-phase, fluid-pump

For the past 6 months there has been increase in my electricity bill. The reason is that the maximum demand is higher (6kW) than the sanctioned maximum demand (3kW.)

We have a 3HP 3 phase borewell motor. We have had the same motor for more than 5 years now and for the past 6 months it seems to be drawing 6.2kW power instead of under 3kW. This borewell motor is also the only load connected to the energy meter.

Nothing has changed in the past 6 months except some re-wiring at the energy meter (this is what I am suspecting.)

The people at electricity board are asking me to increase the sanctioned limit.

The current drawn is ~10 amperes and RYB to neutral voltage is ~230V.

Please help me how to troubleshoot this issue. Nobody here seems to understand that the issue is the motor drawing 6kW while it should be drawing <3kW.

Could bad wiring at energy meter cause this, or a faulty energy meter? Could the motor itself  be faulty? It seems to be doing its job of pumping the water perfectly, though.
[image: The energy meter showing max demand]
[image: connections. Electrician used insulation tape to tag RYB]
[image: The motor started box]

In the second picture, I see there's an additional red wire going into the fuse with Blue phase. I'm not sure where it is coming from.

Comment: Maybe the water table level has dropped thus you need more power.

Comment: wouldn't that require the submersible pump to be lowered? Also, how can a motor rated 3HP draw double the power?

Comment: If a motor should draw 3kW, but you're seeing a consistant 6kW, I'd want to know what kind of controller and fuse you have fitted, as both should failed safe (turned off) if you're constantly drawing twice the expected power. The other question is: why do you think it's this motor? What else is on this supply?

Comment: Like I mentioned, there's no other load connected to the energy meter. Also I checked the energy meter go from 0 to 6kW when I turned on the borewell motor.

Comment: @ArunGowda it's the relative level of the water table surface to the height you are lifting it to that governs the energy needed to lift a litre. It doesn't matter if the pump is one inch below the water surface or 100 metres.

Comment: @Andyaka that has remained a constant too. The motor and where we pump water to has remained the same. And exactly same positions to be precise.

Comment: How do you know the underground water surface level hasn't lowered? Can you be sure?

Comment: But does that really matter? you said `It doesn't matter if the pump is one inch below the water surface or 100 metres.`

Comment: What I meant was : The pump is in the same position from earth surface. say 250 meters. Now does it matter if the water level is 150 meters below earth's surface (100m above pump) or 200 meters(50m above pump) from earth surface?

Comment: You should put up a diagram of the energy meter's wiring.  Double the rated power would not be a good thing and would point to the motor being operated beyond its capacity due to an excessive workload or defective bearings, or by having overheated and shortened out parts of its coil packs.  A vast metered increase at the same time wiring was changed makes the rewiring a prime suspect of course, and without you showing how it is done, one cannot really say a lot.

Comment: This seems like it belongs on [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't really know the circuit. If that is a possibility, I can get the professional electrician to get it checked. I'm looking for a starting point.

Comment: Maybe when they changed your "wiring" they started monitoring apparent power, rather than real power, although a jump of 100% would imply a terrible power factor to begin with. Perhaps, during the "rewiring" they accidentally disabled a bunch of PFC stuff?

Comment: "does [the water level] matter?" Yes. The power required is proportional to the height the water is being lifted through (for a constant flow rate). Assuming the discharge height is fixed then a falling water level in the well (e.g. due to dry weather) will require more power to pump. The distance of the pump below the water level is irrelevant (because the pressure on the inlet side compensates for the back pressure on the outlet side).

Comment: What condition is the pump in? After 5 years it could be due for an inspection and service. You could be using 3 kW heating up the bearings. Can you add photos of the energy meter and other wiring?

Comment: Last time.... you said this: *The pump is in the same position from earth surface. say 250 meters. Now does it matter if the water level is 150 meters below earth's surface (100m above pump) or 200 meters(50m above pump) from earth surface?* <-- yes, it totally matters.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/267613/97780

Comment: "I'm looking for a starting point." Can you check the water level in the well yourself? The next step would be to get a professional electrician (preferably one with borehole pump experience) to check the surface wiring and confirm the real and apparent motor consumption. (It is possible for energy meters to read incorrectly and motors shouldn't be consuming twice their rating.) The final step (because it's presumably quite involved) would be to haul the motor/pump up and have them serviced.

Comment: Interesting first question, which has obviously generated a lot of comment.  You might, however, get a better answer if you provided some more details, and in particular some photos of the energy meter and wiring that has changed.

Comment: 6 kW continuously is instantaneous at start up? How do you measure it?

Comment: The energy meter shows the power in real time. Yes it instantly goes up to 6 from 0

Comment: What energy meter? Does it stay at 6 kW continuously or drop down after startup?

Comment: It continuously draws 6kW.

Comment: Added pictures.

Answer (score 6):

The key question seems to be whether the energy meter is working correctly or not.

Have you measured the current to the pump using an independent meter (such as a clamp on ammeter), or are you reading 10A from the display of the same meter which is giving a suspect power reading?

If the independent current reading is ~10A, then the load has almost certainly changed (and there are lots of good comments on the question as to possible causes).

If the independent reading is nearer 5A, the meter setup is wrong.

If the latter, I'd look at the meter configuration to check the CT ratio (if an indirect meter), and also check how many times the supply leads are passing through the CT window.  I've seen inexperienced engineers pass the cable through twice, unintentionally doubling the metered current.